# How can I overlay SVG diagrams on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I would like to add an overlay image on a Google Map. The image is a SVG file I have generated (Python with SVGFig).

I am using the following code:

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(48.8, 2.4), 12);

    // ground overlay
    var boundaries = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(48.283188032632829, 1.9675270369830129), new GLatLng(49.187215000000002, 2.7771877478303999));
    var oldmap = new GGroundOverlay("test.svg", boundaries);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.addOverlay(oldmap);
}
```

Surprisingly, it works with Safari 4, but it doesn't work with Firefox (with Safari 3, the background is not transparent).

Does anyone have an idea on how I could overlay an SVG?

PS1: I read some works like [this](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/BdccGmapBits.htm) or the source code of swa.ethz.ch/googlemaps, but it seems that they have to use JavaScript code to parse the SVG and add one by one all the elements (but I did not understand all the source...).

PS2: The SVG is composed of different filled paths and circles, with transparency.
If there is no solution to overlay my SVG, I can use 2 alternative solutions:

- rasterize the SVG
- convert the paths and circles in GPolygons

But I do not really like the 1st solution because of the poor quality of the bitmap and the time to generate it with antialiasing.

And for the 2nd solution, the arcs, ellipses and circles will have to be decomposed into small polylines. A lot of them will be necessary for a good result. But I have around 3000 arcs and circles to draw, so...

Comment: What a great question.  My gut feel is that your second approach will not perform, but hesitate to answer without confirming how gmaps performs with that volume of polylines.  I look forward to to seeing how this goes.

Comment: Could it be, that GGroundOverly makes use of CSS background images? FF doesn't handle (yet, 3.5 will) SVGs as backgrounds.

Comment: I just tried with FF 3.5, but it doesn't work, too.
In fact, when I am looking in the downloaded media (Tools/Page Info/Media), my SVG is not loaded at all...

Comment: GGroundOverlays does not use CSS background images. Just regular img's. I don't know why they don't work.

Comment: You can (try to) see the result [here](http://docmatic.fr/temp/toto.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some news (I hope it's better to put them here in an answer, instead of editing my questions or to create a new question. Please feel free to move it if needed, or to tell me, so as I can rectify):

My problem was the following:

```
var oldmap = new GGroundOverlay("test.svg", boundaries);
map.addOverlay(oldmap);
```

did not work on Safari 3, Firefox and Opera (IE is not enable to draw SVG).

In fact, this code produce the insertion (in a `<div>`) of the following element

```
<img src="test.svg" style=".....">
```

And Safari 4 is able to draw a SVG file as an image, but this is not the way to do for the other browser. So the idea is now to create a custom overlay for the SVG, as explained [here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Custom_Overlays).

That's the reason why I asked for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071328/how-to-produce-same-result-on-different-browsers-when-embedding-svg-file-in-html) (I am sorry, but HTML/javascript are not my strongest points).

And since there is a small bug with Webkit for rendering a SVG with transparent background with `<object>`element, I need to use `<object>` or `<img>` accordingly to the browser (I don't like this, but... for the moment, it's still the quick-and-dirty experiments)

So I started with this code (still work in progress):

```
// create the object
function myOverlay(SVGurl, bounds)
{
    this.url_ = SVGurl;
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
}

// prototype
myOverlay.prototype = new GOverlay();

// initialize
myOverlay.prototype.initialize = function(map)
{
    // create the div
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.setAttribute('id',"SVGdiv");
    div.setAttribute('width',"900px");
    div.setAttribute('height',"900px");

    // add it with the same z-index as the map
    this.map_ = map;
    this.div_ = div;

    //create new svg root element and set attributes
    var svgRoot;
    if (BrowserDetect.browser=='Safari')
    {
        // Bug in webkit: with <objec> element, Safari put a white background... :-(
        svgRoot = document.createElement("img");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("id", "SVGelement");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("style","width:900px;height:900px");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("src", "test.svg");
    }
    else //if (BrowserDetect.browser=='Firefox')
    {
        svgRoot = document.createElement("object");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("id", "SVGelement");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("style","width:900px;height:900px;");
        svgRoot.setAttribute("data", "test.svg");
    }


    div.appendChild(svgRoot);
    map.getPane(G_MAP_MAP_PANE).appendChild(div);

    //this.redraw(true);
} 

...
```

The `draw` function is not yet written.

I still have a problem (I progress slowly, thanks to what I read/learn everywhere, and also thanks to people who answer my questions).

Now, the problem is the following : with the `<object>` tag, the map is not draggable. All over the `<object>` element, the mouse pointer is not "the hand icon" to drag the map, but just the normal pointer.

And I did not find how to correct this. Should I add a new mouse event (I just saw mouse event when a click or a double-click append, but not for dragging the map...) ?

Or is there another way to add this layer so as to preserve the drag-ability ?

Thank you for your comments and answers.

PS: I also try to add one by one the elements of my SVG, but... in fact... I don't know how to add them in the DOM tree. In [this example](http://swa.ethz.ch/googlemaps/), the SVG is read and parsed with `GXml.parse()`, and all the elements with a given tag name are obtained (`xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName`) and added to the SVG node (`svgNode.appendChild(node)`). But in my case, I need to add directly the SVG/XML tree (add all its elements), and there are different tags (`<defs>`, `<g>`, `<circle>`, `<path>`, etc.). It is may be simpler, but I don't know how to do.. :(

Answer (score 6):

I spend the last evening on this problem, and I finally found the solution to my problem.

It was not so difficult.

The idea is, as Chris B. said, to load the SVG file with GDownloadUrl, parse it with GXml.parse() and add in the DOM tree every SVG elements I need

To simplify, I have supposed that all the SVG elements was put in a big group called "mainGroup". I have also supposed that some  elements can be in the file.

So here is the library, based on the [Google Maps Custom Overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Custom_Overlays):

```
// create the object
function overlaySVG( svgUrl, bounds)
{
    this.svgUrl_ = svgUrl;
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
}


// prototype
overlaySVG.prototype = new GOverlay();


// initialize
overlaySVG.prototype.initialize = function( map)
{
    //create new div node 
    var svgDiv = document.createElement("div");
    svgDiv.setAttribute( "id", "svgDivison");
    //svgDiv.setAttribute( "style", "position:absolute");
    svgDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    svgDiv.style.top = 0;
    svgDiv.style.left = 0;
    svgDiv.style.height = 0;
    svgDiv.style.width = 0;
    map.getPane(G_MAP_MAP_PANE).appendChild(svgDiv);

    // create new svg element and set attributes
    var svgRoot = document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svgRoot.setAttribute( "id", "svgRoot");
    svgRoot.setAttribute( "width", "100%");
    svgRoot.setAttribute( "height","100%");
    svgDiv.appendChild( svgRoot);

    // load the SVG file
    GDownloadUrl( this.svgUrl_, function( data, responseCode)
    {
        var xml = GXml.parse(data);
        // specify the svg attributes
        svgRoot.setAttribute("viewBox", xml.documentElement.getAttribute("viewBox"));
        // append the defs
        var def = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("defs");
        //for( var int=0; i<def.length; i++)
            svgRoot.appendChild(def[0].cloneNode(true));
        //append the main group
        var nodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("g");
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
            if (nodes[i].id=="mainGroup")
                svgRoot.appendChild(nodes[i].cloneNode(true));
    });

    // keep interesting datas
    this.svgDiv_ = svgDiv;
    this.map_ = map;

    // set position and zoom
    this.redraw(true);
}



// remove from the map pane
overlaySVG.prototype.remove = function()
{
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild( this.div_);
}


// Copy our data to a new overlaySVG...
overlaySVG.prototype.copy = function()
{
    return new overlaySVG( this.url_, this.bounds_, this.center_);
}


// Redraw based on the current projection and zoom level...
overlaySVG.prototype.redraw = function( force)
{
    // We only need to redraw if the coordinate system has changed
    if (!force) return;
    // get the position in pixels of the bound
    posNE = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());      
    posSW = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    // compute the absolute position (in pixels) of the div ...
    this.svgDiv_.style.left = Math.min(posNE.x,posSW.x) + "px";
    this.svgDiv_.style.top = Math.min(posSW.y,posNE.y) + "px";
    // ... and its size
    this.svgDiv_.style.width = Math.abs(posSW.x - posNE.x) + "px";
    this.svgDiv_.style.height = Math.abs(posSW.y - posNE.y) + "px";
}
```

And, you can use it with the following code:

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
{
    //load map
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"), G_NORMAL_MAP);
    // create overlay   
    var boundaries = new GLatLngBounds( new GLatLng(48.2831, 1.9675), new GLatLng(49.1872, 2.7774));
    map.addOverlay( new overlaySVG( "test.svg", boundaries ));
    //add control and set map center
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(48.8, 2.4), 12);
}
```

So, you can use it exactly as you use the `GGroundOverlay` function, except that your SVG file should be created with the Mercator projection (but if you apply it on small area, like one city or smaller, you will not see the difference).

This should work with Safari, Firefox and Opera. You can try my small example [here](http://docmatic.fr/temp/test.html)

Tell me what do you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

This question was briefly discussed on the [Google Maps API Group](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/10b40741f1fe1db5/aeaa203324517d9d?lnk=gst&q=svg#aeaa203324517d9d).  Here's what they said:

> I've not tried it, but SVG is a subset
>   of XML, so you can read them with
>   GDownloadUrl() and analyse them with
>   GXml.parse(). On some wonky webservers
>   you may have to change the file
>   extension to XML.
>
> You then have to crawl through the XML
>   DOM, writing the SVG that you find
>   with document.createElementNS() and
>   .setAttribute() calls...

There are also a some Google Maps SVG examples [here](http://swa.ethz.ch/googlemaps/) and [here](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/BdccGmapBits.htm).

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. Yes, maybe can I  load my file, parse it and insert one by one all my SVG elements. I will try, even if this solution doesn't convince me...
And I am already able to load in one step with GGroundOverlay("test.svg", boundaries) but only with Safari 4...
I will tell you how this goes