# How to add svg to google maps

Tags: google-maps, svg

What am I doing wrong here? I can't seem to add a svg layer onto google maps.

This is the javascript file maps.js

```
function initialize() 
{
      var mapOptions = 
      {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

      var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(-34.397, 150.644), new GLatLng(-34.397, 150.644));
      var oldmap = new GGroundOverlay("test.svg", bounds);
      oldmap.setMap(map);
}
```

this is the html file

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="maps.js"></script>
<body onload = "initialize()">
<div id="googleMap" style="width:80%;height:80%;">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I overlay SVG diagrams on Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055367/how-can-i-overlay-svg-diagrams-on-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

"document.createElement" does not work with SVG elements.  "document.createElementNS" is required.  You have to provide an additional "namespace" argument, "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

Have you considered using CANVAS instead of SVG ?

Comment: What do you mean by document.createElement? I don't have that in my code. I'm basically just calling google map and then I just want to add a layer on top of google maps using svg. I have to use svg file.